# Python Recursion inquiry

Tags: python

I want to confirm if I am understanding how to rewrite this function in recursive form in python.
The function is:

```
# Recurrence Relation
# F(n) = 7 * F(n-1) + 2 * F(n-2)
# F(1) = 1; F(2) = 1
# print (rr(4))
```

and my recursive code is:

```
def rr(n):
  return (2 * rr(n-1) + 2 * rr(n-2))
```

Is this correct? Also, how could I "print" rr(4) as I thought it could only be evaluated when you run the program.

Comment: Missing the base case. There is no stopping this code ever from returning.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the base cases.

```
# F(1) = 1; F(2) = 1
```

Consider:

```
def rr(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 1
    else:
        return 7 * rr(n-1) + 2 * rr(n-2)
```

Also your recursive case didn't match the recurrence relation. It had a `2` where a `7` appeared.

```
>>> def rr(n):
...     if n == 1:
...         return 1
...     elif n == 2:
...         return 1
...     else:
...         return 7 * rr(n-1) + 2 * rr(n-2)
... 
>>> print rr(4)
65
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is going to do a pure stack overflow as you haven't defined your stopping conditions, that are the starting values of F(1) and F(2). Add tests in your function depending on the value of `n` to handle these cases.

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the base cases, which would be the basis for the recursion.

```
def rr(n):
    if n < 1:
        raise "Invalid input"
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    return 7 * rr(n-1) + 2 * rr(n-2)
```

This will run as follows:

```
rr(4) = 7 * rr(4-1) + 2 * rr(4-2)
      = 7 * rr(3) + 2 * rr(2)
      = 7 * (7 * rr(3-1) + 2 * rr(3-2)) + 2 * 1
      = 7 * (7 * r(2) + 2 * r(1)) + 2
      = 7 * (7 * 1 + 2 * 1) + 2
      = 7 * 9 + 2
      = 65
```

As you can see, without having the base cases, your function will run infinitely because `rr(2)` and `rr(1)` never resolve; instead they keep calling the same recursive path `rr(1).. rr(0).. rr(-1)..etc`.